# Using Subsequent Mask in Transformer Leads to NaN Outputs

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, pytorch, transformer

I am trying to implement an autoregressive transformer model similar to the paper *attention is all you need*. From what I have understood, in order to replicate the architecture fully, I need to give the transformer decoder 3 masks.

1. Target subsequent mask: this is for causality.
2. Target padding indexes: just to look at non-padded indices.
3. Encoder padding indices: just to look at non-padded inputs from the encoder.

The snippet is here:

```
y = self.decoder(y, x,
                         tgt_mask=tgt_causal_mask,
                         tgt_key_padding_mask=tgt_padding_mask,
                         memory_key_padding_mask=src_padding_mask)
```

---

With masks being generated like this:

```
def generate_no_peek_mask(self, sz):
    mask = (torch.triu(torch.ones(sz, sz)) == 1).transpose(0, 1)
    mask = mask.float().masked_fill(mask == 0, float("-inf")).masked_fill(mask == 1, float(0.0))
    mask = mask.to(self.device)
    return mask

def generate_padding_mask(self, seq, pad_idx):
    return (seq != pad_idx).to(self.device)
```

The problem is that using these masks leads to issues with the Softmax function because of NaN values. Without these masks, the model does not generate any NaN value. I have tried toying with various input lengths and seeing what happens when I make sure my inputs are moderately big, but it still does not work. The only thing that works is not giving the decoder the masks.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the problem was. It was not from subsequent mask. It was caused by bad `key_padding_mask`. PyTorch expects the `key_padding_mask` to be `true` wherever there is a padding token and `false` wherever there is none. I was generating the padding mask in exactly the opposite way. So the correct mask will be:

```
def generate_padding_mask(self, seq, pad_idx):
    return (seq == pad_idx).to(self.device)
```