# How to make sure which masking arguments I need to provide for calling torch.nn.Transformer model?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, transformer, language-model

The forward function of [PyTorch's Transformer implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html) `torch.nn.Transformer` have a number of masking arguments that are all **optional** :

`forward(src, tgt, src_mask=None, tgt_mask=None, memory_mask=None, src_key_padding_mask=None, tgt_key_padding_mask=None, memory_key_padding_mask=None)`

Parameters:

- src (Tensor) – the sequence to the encoder (required).
- tgt (Tensor) – the sequence to the decoder (required).
- src_mask (Optional[Tensor]) – the additive mask for the src sequence
  (optional).
- tgt_mask (Optional[Tensor]) – the additive mask for the tgt sequence
  (optional).
- memory_mask (Optional[Tensor]) – the additive mask for the encoder
  output (optional).
- src_key_padding_mask (Optional[Tensor]) – the Tensor mask for src
  keys per batch (optional).
- tgt_key_padding_mask (Optional[Tensor]) – the Tensor mask for tgt
  keys per batch (optional).
- memory_key_padding_mask (Optional[Tensor]) – the Tensor mask for
  memory keys per batch (optional).

**If I just want to use a vanilla Transformer, what masking arguments should I provide?** **What are the effects if I do not provide them?**

This is confusing to me because I found people selectively provide masking arguments.

For example, [this one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/97067/using-subsequent-mask-in-transformer-leads-to-nan-outputs) provided everything except `memory_mask` in TransformerDecoder layer. How can I know whether I should provide it or not?

Another example, [this one](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html) uses a look-ahead mask (upper triangular) in the encoder part.

And in [this example](https://buomsoo-kim.github.io/attention/2020/04/21/Attention-mechanism-19.md/), the author didn't input any mask.